# C# Add variable value to list name

Tags: c#

Is it possible to add a variable to a list name when using it?

Something like this:

```
string id = "1"; //Could be 2
List<string> List1 = new List<string> {"1","11" };
List<string> List2 = new List<string> {"2","22" };

foreach (var element in List+id)
{ //code here }
```

IDs could be a dozen different values, so I didn't even try with regular `if()`. Would that be the only way?

Comment: no you can't do that, you might create a list of list of strings though

Comment: Looks like you want a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>)`

Comment: Take a look at reflection in C#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a dictionary:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
dict.Add("1", new List<string> {"1","11" });
dict.Add("2", new List<string> {"2","22" });
```

Then you can do

```
foreach (var element in dict[id])
{ 
}
```

Comment: Should be `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` from the look of the OP

Comment: @MatthewWatson but he is just indexing.

Comment: His `id` is of type `string`, not `int`.

Comment: @MatthewWatson i'm aware of that. but it comes form his idea of creating the variable name. which isn't needed

Comment: Well in that case you could just use a list of lists, and subtract one from the index value, rather than using a dictionary. (Assuming that the ids are incrementing - hard to say from the actual question)

Comment: @MatthewWatson maybe he wants non consecutive indices? who knows

Comment: Indeed, who knows? How do you know that he doesn't want to use strings as the IDs? ;) You should probably ask the OP.

Comment: The "id" value is a random string that could have leading zeros so it's not really an index. I wrote it like that just to keep it short, sorry for the confusion!
Anyway the dictionary is what I needed, thanks.